# C# - Foreach two line in Text File

Tags: c#, xamarin, foreach, console-application

I am developing in `C#`.
I have a `text file` containing the following:

```
Sam
NYC
Mii
Peru
LEO
Argentina
```

I want to iterate through this file two line by two line, then print to the console the `first line, second line` (the Name and the Country) of each couple, so the output would be:

```
Sam, NYC
Mii, Peru
```

Here is what I have tried:

```
int linenum = 0;
        foreach (string line in File.ReadLines("c:\\file.txt"))
        {
            string word = line;
            string s = "";
            string j = "";
            linenum = linenum + 1;
            if(linenum % 2 != 0) //impaire
            {
                s = line;
            }
            else
            {
                j = line;
            }
          Console.WriteLine((string.Concat(s, j));
     }
```

But that's not working, I want to do:

```
 int linenum = 0;
 foreach( two lines in File.ReadLines("c:\\file.txt"))
 {
 linenum = linenum + 1;
 //get the first line (linenum = 1) and store it in a string s
 // then get the second line (linenum = 2) and store it in a string j
 // then print the two strings together to the console like that 
  Console.WriteLine((string.Concat("S: " + s,"J: " j));
 }
```

How can I do that ?

Comment: Don't store related informations in different lines

Comment: In your foreach loop you have to keep track of even-odd state. Remember the odd value and print at even ones.

Comment: If your file is not very big then perhaps you could have a better experience in writing this code using File.ReadAllLines and work with an array of lines all in memory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do your output with `Console.WriteLine` in every line, but you also should do that only for every second line. Furthermore, your variables `s` and `j` live inside the loop's scope, so they are recreated with every iteration and loose their prior value.

```
int i = 0; string prev = "";
foreach (string line in File.ReadLines("c:\\file.txt")) {
    if (i++ % 2 == 0) prev = line;
    else Console.WriteLine($"{prev}, {line}");
}
```

Another approach would be iterating the array you get from `File.ReadAllLines` with an `for` loop instead of `foreach` and increase the index by 2

```
var lines = File.ReadAllLines("c:\\file.txt");
//make sure, you have an even number of lines!
if (lines.Length% 2 == 0) for (int i = 0; i < lines.Length; i+=2) {
   Console.WriteLine($"{lines[i]}, {lines[i+1]}");  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `File.ReadAllLines` to return an array of strings:

```
var lines = File.ReadAllLines(filePath);
for (int i = 0; i < lines.Length; i+=2)
{
    var s = lines[i];
    var j = lines[i+1];
    Console.WriteLine($"S: {s} J: {s}");
}
```

Comment: Without explaining how to use this code in a loop you are not giving a solution to the question

Comment: And it would be considerably less efficient for very large files.

Comment: You are always printing the first two elements of the array!

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you can use LINQ to get two lines in a time using Take

```
var twoLines = File.ReadLines(@"YourPath").Take(2));
```

As you can use Skip to skip the two lines you took and take the next two lines like :

```
var twoLines = File.ReadLines(@"YourPath").Skip(2).Take(2));
```

**EDIT :** Thanks for @derpirscher there were a performance issue so changed the code to the following :

first read the whole file and store it in a string array
then loop through it using LINQ to take two elements from the array in a time.

```
string[] myStringArray = File.ReadAllLines(@"YourFile.txt");
for (int i = 0; i < myStringArray.Length ; i+=2)
   {
      var twoLines = myStringArray.Skip(i).Take(2).ToArray();
   }
```

Comment: Well, this must be the worst performing solution to this problem. First of all, doing the `Count()`, you throw away the advantage of `ReadLines` over `ReadAllLines` because you have to wait for the whole file to be read and put in the collection. Second, you reread the whole file in every loop iteration ...

Comment: Well, I'm didn't think of the performance actually as I didn't try this method before, but I'm not sure about reread the whole file, is it really read the whole file when taking 2 and skip 2 for an example ? If so, I'll reconsider this point and think again

Comment: I'm not sure, whether `ReadLines` only reads as far as you iterate. You may be right there. But when you come towards the end of the file, to `Skip` 10000 lines, you must read them first, there is no way around that.  Then you want to skip 10002 lines, you have to read the first 10000 again, And so on and so forth. So you have to open the file `lineCount/2` times and read `linecount/2` lines in average (fewer at the start, more at the end). All that, assuming, `ReadLine` only reads as far as you iterate.

Comment: @derpirscher you were right there thank you. I've considered the performance issue and wrote the code in another method. just to read once from the file. I think this way is better

Comment: if you're using an array and a `for` loop, there is no need for `Skip` and `Take` just access the values via their index. ie `myStringArray[i]` and `myStringArray[i+1]`

Comment: Definitely,  but continued with linq to correct the performance issue while using different methods.

Answer (score 0):

You can write yourself a little helper method to return batches of lines.

This implementation handles files that are not a multiple of the batch size (2 in your case) by returning `""` for the missing lines at the end of the file.

```
public static IEnumerable<string[]> BatchedLinesFromFile(string filename, int batchSize)
{
    string[] result = Enumerable.Repeat("", batchSize).ToArray();
    int count = 0;

    foreach (var line in File.ReadLines(filename))
    {
        result[count++] = line;

        if (count != batchSize)
            continue;

        yield return result;
        count  = 0;
        result = Enumerable.Repeat("", batchSize).ToArray();
    }

    if (count > 0)
        yield return result;
}
```

Note that this also returns a separate array for each result, in case you make a copy of it.

Given that code, you can use it like so:

```
foreach (var batch in BatchedLinesFromFile(filename, 2))
{
    Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", batch));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another one, using [Enumerable.Repeat()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348899(v=vs.110).aspx) and an interger selector incremented a `[NumberOfLines / 2]` times.
Could be interesting for the `LINQ` addicted (a `for / foreach` solution is probably better anyway).

```
string[] input = File.ReadAllLines([SourcePath]);
int Selector = -1;

string[] output = Enumerable.Repeat(0, input.Length / 2).Select(_ => {
                    Selector += 2;
                    return $"{input[Selector - 1]}  {input[Selector]}";
                }).ToArray();
```

The output is:

```
Sam NYC
Mii Peru
LEO Argentina
```

Answer (score -1):

Use the right tool for the job. `foreach()` is not the right tool here.

Without giving up the memory efficiency of ReadLines() over ReadAll():

```
    using (var lines = File.ReadLines("c:\\file.txt").GetEnumerator())
    {
        while (lines.MoveNext())
        {
            string firstLine = lines.Current;

            if (!lines.MoveNext())
                throw new InvalidOperationException("odd nr of lines");

            string secondLine = lines.Current;

            // use 2 lines

            Console.WriteLine("S: " + firstLine ,"J: " + secondLine);
        }
    }
```